# Excel/Calc gives wrong comparison result (after sending file)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

In Excel I have hours and minutes in format like `10:00`.

`=LEFT(SEARCH(":";R1C1)-1)` helps to get hour.

I use `IF` and compare the output with numbers.

But I find that after uploading and downloading file (from email, e.g.) formula checking like `10<8` or `10>20` gives wrong answer. The problem persist in Excel and in LibreOffice Calc. Why so, and and what to change?

Here is the formula I use (to check if the time is between 8am and 8pm, and give either **CLOSED** or the **time**):

`=IF(LEFT(R1C1; SEARCH(":"; R1C1)-1)<8; "CLOSED"; IF(LEFT(R1C1; SEARCH(":"; R1C1)-1)>20; "CLOSED"; R1C1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Excel/Calc might interprete the output you get with `LEFT` **as text, not number**. Therefore, there is a tweak. Just add `+0` to it. Then `10+0<8` or `10+0>20` will give the right answer.

Here is a possible formula with `+0`:

`=IF(LEFT(R1C1; SEARCH(":"; R1C1)-1)+0<8; "CLOSED"; IF(LEFT(R1C1; SEARCH(":"; R1C1)-1)+0>20; "CLOSED"; R1C1))`

You might as well use `VALUE` function to **convert text values to number values** for number comparisons, without `+0` (for reference, similarly without tweaks like concatenating empty string as `&""`, you can use the `TEXT` function to **convert number to text**).